# Word VSTO Add-In

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I'm developing an Add-In for Microsoft Office Word and I've encountered an unusual situation. In my Add-In, I want to add few more options when user right clicks a table cell. I wrote a small function which handles creation/search of my add-in buttons:

```
    private Office.CommandBarButton AppendBarButton(Office.CommandBar cmdBar, string tag, string caption, int? faceid = null, bool begingroup = false)
    {
        if (cmdBar == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("Command bar argument cannot be null.");
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tag)) throw new ArgumentException("Invalid tag.");
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(caption)) throw new ArgumentException("Invalid caption.");

        Office.CommandBarButton btn = cmdBar.Controls.OfType<Office.CommandBarButton>().FirstOrDefault(ctrl => ctrl.Tag == tag);
        if (btn == null) btn = (Office.CommandBarButton)cmdBar.Controls.Add(Office.MsoControlType.msoControlButton, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true);
        if (btn == null) throw new ApplicationException("Could not create the command bar button.");

        btn.Tag = tag;

        if (faceid != null)
        {
            btn.Style = Office.MsoButtonStyle.msoButtonIconAndCaption;
            btn.BuiltInFace = true;
            btn.FaceId = (int)faceid;
        }
        else btn.Style = Office.MsoButtonStyle.msoButtonCaption;

        btn.Caption = caption;
        btn.BeginGroup = begingroup;

        return btn;
    }
```

Now, from the ribbon load handler, i do something like this:

```
    var tableCellsBar = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.CommandBars["Table Cells"];
    var someBtn = AppendBarButton(tableCellsBar, "HardCodedTag", "SomeCaption", 989);
    someBtn.Click += SomeBtnClickHandler; // [!!!]
```

Now here's the strange part. This works just fine. I test it on my development laptop, it works just fine. I deploy it on my other laptop (via publishing, then install it on the laptop), and it works, just fine again. However, on my client's two laptops, I deploy it the same way as on my other laptop, but it seems like it doesn't work. All 4 laptops have Office 2016 installed. Everything else from the Add-In works, except this thing.

I can't be sure that the problem is somewhere in this part of the code, but here's the thing. I have try/catch & logging pretty much all around the code. Everything logs exactly like it should on all laptops, except for `SomeBtnClickHandler` (marked with [!!!]). It seems like when I press the button on my client's laptops, the handler doesn't get invoked at all (and yes, that does seem to be the problem since on my 2 laptops, the functionality of that handler happens and I can see the change - like it really got invoked, however on my client's laptops, absolutely nothing happens, neither the expected change in the document, nor the logs). I was at least expecting if the `AppendBarButton()` function wasn't working properly, the line [!!!] would throw some kind of exception, or maybe even NRE.

I'm still new to this VSTO thing so I may be overlooking some simple thing.

Comment: The CommandBars object model is deprecated since the introduction of the full RibbonX functionality with Office 2010. I suggest you use Ribbon XML (not the Designer) to add a button to this short cut menu.

Comment: @CindyMeister I'll try, thanks for the suggestion.